# Electron sqlite3 package app module not found

Tags: node.js, module, sqlite, package, electron

When I run the packaged electron app for windows(which includes sqlite3), I get the following error:

```
Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win32-ia32\resour
ces\app.asar\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v2.0-win32-ia32\node_sqli
te3.node'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win
32-ia32\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win32-ia32\resour
ces\app.asar\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win32-ia32\resour
ces\app.asar\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:190:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Client_SQLite3._driver (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win32-ia32\re
sources\app.asar\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:75:12)
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Shoppinglist2-win3
2-ia32\resources\app.asar\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:219:26)
```

If I package the app for Linux it workes fine.

PS: Sqlite3 is included as a normal dependency and if i execute the app by npm start it workes fine. And I took care of the rebuild process
Thank you :-)

Comment: the binary module is build into `node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node`, but needs to be placed in `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v2.0-win32-ia32/node_sqlite3.node` to be correctly loaded